# Validate multiple cell data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck in a bit of a pickle could someone please help.
I am trying to check if each property has a particular property_id.

**Eg:- verify if each of the property has property if "ABC, XYZ, LMN, IJK". Also verify if each of date is > 10-12-2018**

```
| Property | Property_ID | Date       |
|----------|-------------|------------|
| A        | ABC         | 10/12/2018 |
| A        | XYZ         | 08/11/2018 |
| A        | LMN         | 12/05/2018 |
| A        | IJK         | 15/05/2018 |
| B        | ABC         | 13/12/2018 |
| B        | XYZ         | 14/10/2018 |
| B        | IJK         | 15/12/2018 |
| C        | LMN         | 01/12/2018 |
| C        | XYZ         | 17/05/2018 |
```

```
Expected Result
    | Property | Property_ID | Date       | Result     |
    |----------|-------------|------------|------------|
    | A        | ABC         | 10/12/2018 |
    | A        | XYZ         | 08/11/2018 |
    | A        | LMN         | 12/05/2018 |
    | A        | IJK         | 15/05/2018 |All PID's are found
    | B        | ABC         | 13/12/2018 |
    | B        | XYZ         | 14/10/2018 |
    | B        | IJK         | 15/12/2018 |LMN is missing for Property B
    | C        | LMN         | 01/12/2018 |
    | C        | XYZ         | 17/05/2018 |ABC, IJK is missing for property C
```

MY Logic:

```
'CREATING VARIABLE TO ACCESS SHEET RANGE
sheetName1 = "test"                          'sheetName SHOULD BE EQUAL TO WORKSHEET NAME (REPLACE THE NAME ACCORDINGLY)
Set sht1 = Sheets(sheetName1)

'FINDING TOTAL NUMBER OF ROWS PRESENT IN THE ACTIVE WORKSHEET
totalRowCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName1).Range("A1", Worksheets(sheetName1).Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

previous_Value = sht1.Range("A2")
current_Value = Null

'Creating Flags to verify value
ABC = False
XYZ = False
IJK = False
LMN = False
OPQ = False
Date_Validation = Null

For i = 2 To totalRowCount
current_Value = Trim(sht1.Range("A" & i))
If current_Value = previous_Value Then
    promotion_ID = Trim(sht1.Range("B" & i))

    'Validate date
    Date = "10-12-2018"

    If promotion_ID = "ABC" Then
        ABC = True
    ElseIf promotion_ID = "IJK" Then
        IJK = True
    ElseIf promotion_ID = "XYZ" Then
        XYZ = True
    End If

    'FULL SERVICE
    If promotion_ID = "LMN" Then
        LMN = True
    ElseIf promotion_ID = "OPQ" Then
        OPQ = True
    ElseIf promotion_ID = "QWE" Then
        QWE = True
    End If
Else
    sht1.Range("D" & i) = "Here i need to display msg of flag which is not found"
    previous_Value = sht1.Range("A" & i)
End If
```

Comment: Btw ABC etc will be initialised as False if declared as Boolean. And you can use one Select Case statement for all of those two If Else If blocks.

Comment: What's your question? You didn't ask one. What is wrong with your code? What errors do you get and where? What does happen versus what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Question:- Is there a easier way to verify if each property(A2,A3,A4,A5) has corresponding property_id(B2,B3,B4,B5) as mentioned above.

What is expected:
I Want to write a comment if the any Property_ID is not present for any of the Property

Comment: Did you declare your variable? Where? (hint: don't use implicit declarations, and always put Option Explicit at the top of modules).

Comment: `Date = "10-12-2018"`: Do you really want to change the system [date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-statement)?

Comment: My bad..
That is just a temp variable.. it is validate_date = "10-12-2018"

Comment: So how is the data part relevant? I have a better understanding now of the id part.

Comment: Can you show the expected output as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: 1. My 1st loop should only refer to Property "A" and its corresponding Property_ID's i.e "ABC,XYZ,IJK,LMN"
2. 2nd should refer to "B" and its correesponding ID's
3. 3rd should refer to C .... so on and so forth

Comment: I guess your original data is always like the example you posted, I mean, not duplicates or stuff like that, right?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes. It is almost relevant

Comment: There are different ways of accomplishing what you want. But if your code is giving the results you require, just use it.  Working with the data in a VBA array would be faster, and using User Defined Objects and Dictionaries might be more easily modifiable in the future, but unless your code is slow, or to difficult to modify for different scenarios, why go to the bother?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a couple of problems in the code:

1. Your setting your "valid date" value *inside* your loop;
   a. it will never change;
   b. it's not being compared to anything to trigger an exception.
   c. the current "Date" should be initialized from the first record, outside the loop and `Date_validation` should be set based on this first value, such as:
   `Date_validation = Date = Trim(sht1.Range("c2"))`
   Therefore "Date_validation" is only set true when the date is valid, any false value is an exception.
   d. A side note: a var named "Date" is liable to run into keyword issues... may I suggest "PropDate" or "PromoDate".
   e. Each new line read (i incremented) should test not only is `date_validation
2. If your `If current_Value = previous_Value Then` is false (ie new property),  you haven't checked if all of the conditions have been met, only that your' now sitting on a new property.  The corresponding `Else` should likely be an `ElseIf` such as:
   `ElseIf not (ABC and IJK and XYZ and ... and Date_validation )  'only if all false
                                                                   '.... display error message
                                                                   ' also all if the ABC (etc) ...
                                                                 ' triggers need  to be reset to false
                                                                 ' along with Data_validation`
3. At the point of the message in the code, `i` has already incremented and is sitting on a new record `i`.  it should probably read (something) `i-1`